# PHP: How to display 2 column values in dropdownlist

Tags: php, sql, database

I have this code:

```
echo "<select name='brand'"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
foreach ($dbo->query($quer3) as $noticia3) 
{
    if($noticia3['id']==@$brand)
    {
        echo  "<option selected value='$noticia3[id]'>$noticia3[brand]</option>"."<BR>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<option value='$noticia3[id]'>$noticia3[brand]</option>";
    }
}
```

I want is to add another column to be displayed into the drop down list.
For example:

```
echo  "<option selected value='$noticia3[id]'>$noticia3[brand]+$noticia3[site]</option>"."<BR>";
```

As you can see, I want to add the "site" column.
What to do?

Comment: select site column in the query. show the query

Comment: Well, I don't know if it happened when you pasted your code or what, but you have a syntax error, look at the editors color coding. - I'm not entirely sure what is going wrong? I mean why not just do the same thing for site as you have with brand?

Comment: @Jpec I already added site in the query. My problem is I don't know how to concat them when inside echo

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```php
echo "<select name='brand'"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
foreach ($dbo->query($quer3) as $noticia3) 
{
    if($noticia3['id']==@$brand)
    {
        echo  "<option selected value='$noticia3[id]'>" . $noticia3[brand] . " " . $noticia3[site] . "</option><br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<option value='$noticia3[id]'>" . $noticia3[brand] . " " . $noticia3[site] . "</option>";
    }
}
```

This should work for the solution you want.

Comment: sorry, I have another problem, how to default show the "Select one", because mine is defaulting the last dropdownvalue

Comment: change the following: <option value=''> Select one</option> to <option value=''  selected="selected">Select one</option>

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Use dot(.) operator instead of (+)

```
echo  "<option selected value='$noticia3[id]'>".$noticia3[brand]."".$noticia3[site]."</option>"."<BR>";
```